# Error: double* RealsSet::operator=(const RealsSet&)' cannot be overloaded

Tags: c++

Error:

```
'double* RealsSet::operator=(const RealsSet&)' cannot be overloaded
```

My code is basically a vector-like class. I defined some operators, but when it comes to the `=` operator, I can't define two, the first one is an assignment operator and the second one is a conversion operator.

```
class RealsSet{

private :
    int rsize, maxsize;
    double* real;
public :
    RealsSet() : maxsize(5) , rsize(0) , real(new double[maxsize]) {
    }
    RealsSet(vector <double>& v): maxsize(v.size()+5-(v.size()%5)) , rsize(v.size()) , real(new double[maxsize]) {
        for(int i=0;i<rsize;i++){
            real[i]=v[i];
        }
    } 
 ...
    RealsSet& operator=(const RealsSet& r){
        if(this != &r){
            delete[] real;
            rsize=r.rsize;
            maxsize=r.maxsize;
            real = new double[maxsize];
            for(int i=0;i<rsize;i++){
                real[i]=r.real[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    double* operator=(const RealsSet& r){
        return r.real;
    }
};
```

Comment: You cannot overload based only on return type.

Comment: And this is not a conversion operator. For that you need to overload a typecast to double.

Comment: See [cast_operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for information on conversion operators.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- that like article is **not** about a **cast operator**; it's about a **conversion operator**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The conversion operator can be applied in situations that do not involve a cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker I guess I must have gotten the terms confused because of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you try to overload a function only by its return type, which is not possible.

If it was possible, then what should the compiler do about ambiguities like this?

```
RealsSet my_set;
my_set = another_set; // return value discarded
```

> the second one is a conversion operator

It isn't. If you want a conversion operator, do as follows:

```
operator double*() const {
    return r.real;
}
```

Better yet, forget about the conversion operator and implement an explicit conversion function which will create fewer surprises:

```
double* get_real() const {
    return real;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) instead?

```
operator double*() const { return r.real; }
```

Comment: That's a **conversion operator**. It can be applied in situations where the conversion is implicit, and it can be applied when the conversion is explicit. There is no "implicit conversion operator".

Comment: @PeteBecker - You're right, but as of c++11, there's an explicit conversion operator. How would you suggest one distinguish between the two unambiguously?

Comment: @KossayRhafiri - You should also consider the advice in [Christian Hackl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285759/344638).

Comment: @antiduh -- "conversion operator" and "implicit conversion operator" capture the difference.